ARIMAX: only MA(1) model gives meaningful coefficients for exogenous variables
Is it possible that the coefficients for the exogenous variables in (regression with ARIMA errors) are only meaningful with MA(1) models?
Here is my reasoning and a simulation.  I would be grateful for any guidance.  I have an engineering background with only undergrad-level stats.
Consider a dynamic process for a dependent variable y that responds to two independent variables x1, x2.
There is a steady state model that describes the value of y reached after a period of time.  ys = 30 + 100 x1 + 200 x2.
There is a rate constant k that controls the approach to steady state.  dy/dt = k(ys - y).
This describes any first-order physical process, for example,
y = the temperature of a bagel in a toaster 
x1 = pressing down the lever to begin toasting 
x2 = pressing the "bagel" button to further elevate the coil temperatures
A simple version of the heat equation is dT/dt = k(T0 - T) where T0 is the temperature of the coil and T the temperature of the bagel.  Let's make a simple model of the coil temperature assuming it responds instantaneously to the inputs T0 = b0 + b1 x1 + b2 x2.
I simulated my data with room temperature as 30 degrees, pressing the lever heats to 130, and then pressing the button heats to 330 degrees.  The bagel will gradually heat - this is shown by the solution for y in the below plot.
If x1 and x2 have values of zero or one for pressing the lever and the button, then b0 measures room temperature (30 degrees), b1 measures the additional degrees that pressing the lever heats the coil above room temperature (+100 degrees), and b2 the additional degrees that pressing the button gives (+200 degrees).  The value of k has units of 1/sec and describes empirically the rate of heat transfer from the coil to the bagel.
I imagine this simple ODE system could model other dynamic processes approximately.  I'm not a social scientist, but I imagine there are some dynamics after the application of an intervention and an eventual steady state.
Let's say I have observations of the bagel temperature and I want to measure the coefficients for x1 and x2 on dynamic data.  It's natural to fit a regression model with ARIMA errors for y with exogenous regressors x1, x2.
In the equation dy/dt = k(ys - y), it seems to me that the driving force for the approach to steady state ys - y is related to the MA(1), x1, and x2 terms.  It seems that there is no role for the AR terms or higher-order MA terms.  And possibly, including these terms will destroy the relationship we would like to fit.
I simulated some data by integrating the above ODE and fit two regression models.  I fit one model with auto.arima for automatic model selection.  The coefficients for x1 and x2 are wrong and close to zero.  b1 = 0.1, b2 = 0.2.
I fit a second model with only MA(1).  The coefficients are much closer to the model that generated the data.  b1 = 68, b2 = 181.  I suppose there is some error created by the approximation of the ODE integration by the basic arithmetic of the MA(1) term.
edit: I wonder if the MA(1) model with exogenous regressors is equivalent to integrating an ODE with the Euler method, and we can expect some error in the estimate in a similar way that Euler method creates integration error that is addressed by Runge-Kutta.
library(tidyverse)
library(deSolve)
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo


# functions for generating dynamic data ----
  
  
fn <- function(x1, x2) {
  # predict steady state response from predictors
  30 + 100 * x1 + 200 * x2
}


calc_dy_dt <- function(t, y, p) {
  # return the derivative
  # first-order approach to steady state
  
  x1 <- approx(p$data$t, p$data$x1, t, rule = 2)$y
  x2 <- approx(p$data$t, p$data$x2, t, rule = 2)$y
  
  dy_dt <- p$k * (fn(x1, x2) - y)
  list(dy_dt)
}


integrate_y <- function(data, k) {
  # integrate the ode to produce dynamic response
  # and add as new column to the data frame
  
  soln <- ode(
    data$ys[1],
data$t,
    calc_dy_dt,
    lst(data, k)
  )
  
  data |> 
    add_column(y = soln[, 2])
}


plot_solution <- function(data) {
  # plot predictor, steady-state response, and dynamic response
  
  data |> 
    pivot_longer(-t) |> 
    mutate(
      label = case_match(name, "ys" ~ "steady state solution", "y" ~ "dynamic solution", .default = "input"),
      name = factor(name, c("x1", "x2", "ys", "y")),
      label = factor(label, c("input", "steady state solution", "dynamic solution"))
    ) |> 
    ggplot() + aes(t, value, color = label) + geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y")
}


# sample data ----

dat <- tibble(
  t = 1:100,
  x1 = if_else(t < 20, 0, 1),
  x2 = if_else(t < 50, 0, 1),
  ys = fn(x1, x2)
)

dat <- dat |> 
  integrate_y(0.1)


# plot ----

dat |> 
  plot_solution() |> 
  print()




# models ----

model <- auto.arima(dat$y, xreg = dat |> select(x1, x2) |> as.matrix())

model |> 
  print()
#> Series: dat$y 
#> Regression with ARIMA(5,1,0) errors 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4     ar5      x1      x2
#>       1.6899  -1.3043  0.9268  -0.5569  0.1946  0.1234  0.2463
#> s.e.  0.0979   0.1882  0.2084   0.1856  0.0959  0.4495  0.4497
#> 
#> sigma^2 = 1.47:  log likelihood = -157.72
#> AIC=331.44   AICc=333.04   BIC=352.2

model_ma <- Arima(dat$y, order = c(0, 0, 1), xreg = dat |> select(x1, x2) |> as.matrix())

model_ma |> 
  print()
#> Series: dat$y 
#> Regression with ARIMA(0,0,1) errors 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ma1  intercept       x1        x2
#>       0.7122    35.0462  68.6714  181.5979
#> s.e.  0.0546    10.0105  12.3623   10.1697
#> 
#> sigma^2 = 730.1:  log likelihood = -469.86
#> AIC=949.73   AICc=950.37   BIC=962.75

Created on 2024-06-03 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you, Steven, but I don't think that link covers my question.

I unfortunately can't follow all of your argument. But it may be helpful to consider that ARIMAX is not the same as ARIMAX, or to be more precise, standard auto-ARIMA software fits a regression on the predictors plus an ARIMA model on the residuals, not textbook ARIMAX, see https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/. So since the regression is done before its residuals are modeled using ARIMA, it seems like your title question would not make sense in this model.

Because I am using auto.arima and Arima from the forecast package, I believe that I am fitting the models "the right way" and thus my question is unrelated to that blog post.  My question is more about "what is the relationship between (time series models with exogenous regressions) and (ODE models)?" and less about the different flavors of ARIMAX.  Admittedly, I am a pure practitioner, and my theory is weak.

Hi:  It's an interesting thing that you're trying to model and too complex for me to say anything terribly useful ( without working on it myself and even then who knows ). But I see one issue. Don't make them exogenous regressors to an arima model. Those variables ARE the variables of the model. So, they can be exogenous but not to ARIMA model. I would DEFINITELY check out Harvey's  "econometric time series analysis" and particularly partial adjustment models. It's really the only book ( atleast statistics-econometrics related ) that I know of that talks in depth about these type of problems.

Note that, in any standard time-series econometrics text, you;ll find material on the ARDL and particularly the koyck distributed lag ( this is related to what you're doing indirectly ) but I still recommend Harvey above. It's better than the standard treatment in those books.

Rob Hyndman (the author of that blog post) is the maintainer of both the forecast and the fable packages and explicitly notes at the very bottom of the post that he implemented regression with ARIMA errors, not textbook ARIMAX. And what "the right way" is is quite open to discussion...

I think I understand.  Is it just that I am using the term "ARIMAX" incorrectly?

This what I'm referring to. I had the title wrong.  It's not terribly popular  and it's old but very under-rated. Harvey is not easy to read because he has a very terse style but if you keep your nose in it, you can get a lot of out of it.  Andrew Harvey: "Econometric Analysis of Time Series". It's on amazon for around 70.00.

I edited my post with language "regression with ARIMA errors" and with elaboration of the bagel example.  The data and plots should reflect more intuitively the dynamic heating of the bagel.

@mlofton I agree that doing OLS on the data is very straightforward and could produce adequate coefficients in many cases.  But what about systems where the exogenous variables are constantly changing and the system is almost always in a dynamic state?  A model without any dynamics would treat this all as error.  The quality of fit would be poor, and the residuals would be autocorrelated.

Hi Arthur:  I'm not sure if I implied it but I DEFINITELY did not mean to imply that you should use OLS. That won't work because it's not dynamic. You need a dynamic model ( t subscripts ) that has an error term that leads to a partial adjustment model. If you read about dynamic models and partial adjustment in Harvey's book, you'll see more what I'm referring to. It's difficult to explain a whole book ( well really a couple of chapters called. They are dynamic models I and II IIRC )  in a comment. But I suggest that you not just jump to those chapters and read the book from the beginning.

If you have any questions after going through what I suggested, feel free to ask back here. I think what you're doing is interesting and the plots you made show that you know what you're doing.

if you can't get your hands on harvey, another book that doesn't do a bad job with ARDL's, the koyck distributed lag and partial adjustment is Baltagi. But there's not better book than Harvey in my opinion.

This is the baltagi text I'm referring to. He has a few different ones. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-80149-6
